# Read TIFF file, modify text layer, then save as

Tags: c#, asp.net

Title say it all, I need to do a really simple task in ASP.NET (targeting .NET framework 4.5+ / Core 1.0+):

1. Read a TIFF file (that contains a text layer)
2. Change the text in that text layer
3. Save the modified image as PNG

I tried to do this using `ImageProcessor`, but it seems to support the creation of text layers (ie. it doesn't support layer modification)

Any idea, please?

Comment: Is [this](http://imageprocessor.org/) what you're talking about?

Comment: @MickyD Yes, but I'm open to other libraries / code samples if ImageProcessor can't do it

Comment: Any code to show?  Otherwise you know asking for _libs_ is off-topic for SO. [ask].  Wishing you well